# Stacked templates in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, tilt

Does Sinatra has a built-in way to do stacked Tilt templates, in the way that Sprockets do?

So that I could, for example, have

```
document.erb.markdown
```

to have the document first go from Markdown to HTML with ERB injections, and from there on to HTML via ERB eval? Something like

```
get '/document' do
  render_stacked :document
end
```

And still render it using a built-in method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box *Sinatra* does not have such an option, but there are a lot of workarounds on github. Original one, AFAIK, is [this](https://github.com/kalasjocke/sinatra-asset-pipeline).

Google search should help you [to find](sinatra asset pipeline) a suitable for you.